Bulk delete 'Global Attributes' in WooCommerce via WP-CLI?
Is it possible to delete the global product attributes in WooCommerce by using WP-CLI?
I've often cleared out Users, Orders, and other items using something like this...
wp post delete $(wp post list --post_type='shop_order' --format=ids) --force

But I can't seem to find or figure out a good way to sort that for attributes.
I'm specifically referring to the attributes you configure under 'Products => Attributes' in the WordPress Dashboard not the ones that are added inline on products.

As we know WooCommerce product attributes are stored in a custom taxonomy, It means we need to work with taxonomies and terms instead of posts. WP-CLI provides commands for working with taxonomies and terms that can be used for this purpose.
We are going to follow the given steps:
List all global product attributes > Delete all terms in each global attribute taxonomy
We will use the given CLI to list out all taxonomies so we can identify our attribute taxonomies.
wp taxonomy list --format=json | jq '.[] | select(.name | startswith("pa_"))'
We will use given CLI to delete all terms we have in a specific taxonomy.
wp term list pa_color --field=term_id | xargs wp term delete pa_color
Here we need to replace pa_color with the actual taxonomy you want to delete terms from.
